# Mac OS X .lnk with argument

Tags: macos, tcl

I want to create mac desktop shortcut **programmatically** from tcl script. The shortcut should run:

```
wish /path/to/app.tcl &
```

I do it on windows with .lnk file and on linux with .desktop file. So far I've created bash script with above line, it's almost ok, except two drawbacks: it pops up console window alongside target app and it has grey terminal-ish icon. Both things make it look ugly although console window is worse.

1. I understand mac has "alias" files analogous to windows .lnk. Does this format support argument so I can run "wish app.tcl"? If it does, how can I create such file from tcl?
2. Any alternative ways to create launcher on desktop without aforementioned drawbacks?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112197/what-does-a-app-file-actually-do for useful information. But I've no experience with making .app files despite using the platform; I personally like having that console window…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out .app format is what I need. It is not a file like .lnk or .desktop, but a directory with certain content. The following tcl script wraps any shell script and an icon into an .app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

if {$argc != 3} { error "usage: script-to-app appname script icon.icns" }
lassign $argv appname script icon

file mkdir "$appname.app/Contents/Resources" "$appname.app/Contents/MacOS"
file copy $script "$appname.app/Contents/MacOS/s"
file copy $icon "$appname.app/Contents/Resources/i.icns"

set f [open "$appname.app/Contents/Info.plist" w]
puts $f {
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>s</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
        <string>i</string>
</dict>
</plist>}
close $f
```

Usage:

```
script-to-app "My App" run.sh myicon.icns
```

Note 1: run.sh needs to contain shebang and be executable, otherwise might not work. In my case it was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
wish "/path/to/script.tcl"
```

Note 2: .icns is a special apple icon format, there are online converters that can make .icns from earthly formats.

Thanks to Mark Setchell for suggesting using the automator, it's not what I needed but set me in the right direction.

Comment: I would recommend looking at and/referring to a more authoritative source of information on this topic: [Tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/12987#pagetoc537c3c63)

Comment: @mrcalvin tried solution from Tcl wiki, it did not work for me, outdated probably. Just FYI

Answer (score 4):

Start **Automator** by using a *"Spotlight Search"*, i.e. press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>spacebar</kbd> and start typing *"Automator"*, when it guesses correctly, hit <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>.

Now tell it you want to make a **New Application**. Then select **Utilities** on the left side (`1` in figure) and double-click **Run Shell Script** just beside that (`2` in figure).

On the right side a new window will open (`3` in figure) and put your code in  there.

[image]

Click `File` menu, and hold down the `alt` key and **Save as an application** on your Desktop.

---

Next, you will doubtless want to change the icon from the little fat Automator boy - are we allowed to say that any more? Probably not - oops!

Anyway, select the image you want to use as the icon and open it in **Preview** by tapping <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and then selecting *"Open in Preview"*. Once it opens, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to select and copy it to the Clipboard.

Now select your shiny, new App by single clicking it and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to open its **Info** window. At the top of the **Info** window, left-click the fat boy and then select `Edit` and `Paste` from the menu at the top left of the screen and the logo will change. Job done!

Comment: I meant to do it via tcl programmatically (just clarified my question). On the other hand what your steps produce is a stub app which works like I wanted. I'll try to generate such app from tcl and will let know if it works.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see. I thought the problems were the console popping up and the icon - both of which I addressed, but the problem was actually using Tcl to create the app. Maybe the stub can be examined and its contents generated with Tcl - I haven't thought about that aspect yet!

Comment: .app turned out easy enough to generate. Thanks for the suggestion.